# Escape @ symbol in Innodb Full Text Search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, innodb

Is there anyway to escape `@` in innodb full text search. I have a `table` with `email` column.

What I need is to return all values which contains `@` symbol.

```
SELECT   id
FROM     table
WHERE    ( MATCH (table.email) AGAINST ('+@+' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
AND      id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
```

But this gives syntax error as MySQL doc says @ cannot be used in the query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Can I escape them or any other way from php ?

Comment: A fulltext search is usefull when you look for the beginning of words (because it is an ordered list of all the words, even if a column contains several words). If you have a column with just one email adress in it, a fulltext search is not what you are looking for (for several reasons). Instead, use `where table.email like '%@%'`

Comment: this is just an example of email column, I also have a column say `operator` with only `@` value in it. Can I somehow handle that using FTS ?

Comment: I don't get it: if you have only `@` in a field, then why would you want to use fulltext search at all? Can you pls describe your actual question, rather than trying to force a solution that may not be suitable?

Comment: `@` in a field means there is a column with value **containing** @ symbol (sorry for mentioning only @ before) I have an environment where FTS is mandatory to be used. I have this working using Like operator

Comment: Fulltext indexes split sentences at delimiters. `@` is one (unless you e.g. modify the character map), so an email `test@email.com` will be listed in the index 3 times (if you set the min length to <=3) with: `test`, `email`, `com`. Also: A fulltext index searches for the start of a word only. You cannot search for texts in the middle, e.g. `*@*`, so not treating `@` as a delimiter will not help either. To find a single `@` you COULD: remove it as a delimiter, reduce min word length to 1, use `against ('"@"' in boolean mode)`. Though, again, a fulltext search does not make any sense here!

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH(email) AGAINST ('+test +email +com' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND email LIKE 'test@email.com`
```

This will *first* do the `FULLTEXT` search, and do it fast.  For each row that matched, it will do the extra check.

Caution: `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is probably 3, so something like `ab@xyz.com` should avoid including `+ab`.  At the extreme, avoid the `MATCH` for `ab@cd.tv`, since all tokes are too short.

That is, you need some client code to construct the `MATCH...AGAINST`.